# How to change 'ft_min_word_len' in WAMPSERVER?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I can't figure out where it is located. I only find a 'my.ini' file which doesnt have a 'mysqld' section in it...

Do I have to upload my website to an ACTUAL server before attempting this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says : [11.8.6. Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) :

> For example, if you want
>   three-character words to be
>   searchable, you can set the
>   `ft_min_word_len` variable by putting
>   the following lines in an option file:
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> ft_min_word_len=3
> ```
>
> Then restart the server and rebuild
>   your `FULLTEXT` indexes. Note
>   particularly the remarks regarding
>   `myisamchk` in the instructions
>   following this list.

So, I suppose, if there is no `[mysqld]` section in your `my.ini` file, you'll just have to add one, restart the MySQL server, and voila ;-)